# LCM of large numbers in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, math, greatest-common-divisor, lcm

I'm using the formula "product of two number is equal to the product of their GCD and LCM".

Here's my code :

```
# Uses python3

import sys

def hcf(x, y):

    while(y):
        x, y = y, x % y

    return x

a,b = map(int,sys.stdin.readline().split())

res=int(((a*b)/hcf(a,b)))
print(res)
```

It works great for small numbers. But when i give input as :

> Input:
> 226553150 1023473145
>
> My output:
> 46374212988031352
>
> Correct output:
> 46374212988031350

Can anyone please tell me where am I going wrong ?

Comment: Use `//` rather than `/` ?

Comment: @JohnColeman How will the floor division affect the result ?

Comment: It will avoid loss of precision which true division will have when converting to floating point.

Comment: The problem is solved. Thanks mate !

Answer (score 6):

Elaborating on the comments. In Python 3, true division, `/`, converts its arguments to floats. In your example, the true answer of `lcm(226553150, 1023473145)` is `46374212988031350`. By looking at `bin(46374212988031350)` you can verify that this is a 56 bit number. When you compute `226553150*1023473145/5` (5 is the gcd) you get `4.637421298803135e+16`. Documentation suggests that such floats only have 53 bits of precision. Since 53 < 56, you have lost information. Using `//` avoids this. Somewhat counterintuitively, in cases like this it is "true" division which is actually false.

By the way, a useful module when dealing with exact calculations involving large integers is [fractions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fractions.html) (*):

```
from fractions import gcd
def lcm(a,b):
    return a*b // gcd(a,b)

>>> lcm(226553150,1023473145)
46374212988031350
```

(*) I just noticed that the documentation on `fractions` says this about its `gcd`: "Deprecated since version 3.5: Use math.gcd() instead", but I decided to keep the reference to `fractions` since it is still good to know about it and you might be using a version prior to 3.5.

Comment: That was an amazing explanation. Thanks for that.
I was not allowed to use any other library other than 'sys', that's the reason i wasn't using them.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a different method to find the **GCD** that will be the issue:

Use:

```
def hcfnaive(a, b):
    if(b == 0):
        return abs(a)
    else:
        return hcfnaive(b, a % b)
```

You can try one more method:

```
import math
a = 13
b = 5
print((a*b)/math.gcd(a,b))
```